# How do I update each dependency in bower.json to the latest version?

Tags: json, node.js, package, bower

For example here are dependencies from bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
  "socket.io-client": "1.2.1",
  "underscore": "~1.6.0",
  "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0"
}
```

I can see underscore has a newer 1.7.0 version and bootstrap has a newer version of 3.3.1.
If it was npm then I would change versions to *

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "*",
  "socket.io-client": "*",
  "underscore": "*",
  "angular-bootstrap": "*"
}
```

and run npm update --save
npm would then download all the latest versions and replace * in the package.json file.
However this doesn't work with bower.
How do I get bower to do the same thing and update all the packages at once to the newest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Tilde Ranges which allows patch-level changes if a minor version is specified on the comparator. Allows minor-level changes if not.
For example:

```
~3.1.1 := >=3.1.1 <3.(1+1).0 := >=3.1.1 <3.2.0
```

In your case it means that for the dependencies you defined with the tilde range and specify major.minor.patch version (such as ~3.1.1) you will get the latest patch version.

You can use `"latest"` as the version target and get the latest version, for example: `"bootstrap": "latest"`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about version syntax. This led me to read the full spec here https://github.com/npm/node-semver
The "latest" works and indeed brings the latest version. However it doesn't update the bower.json as npm does when you put in the "*" as a version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use the following keywords

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "latest",
  "socket.io-client": "latest",
  "underscore": "latest",
  "angular-bootstrap": "latest"
}
```

This shall work when you run **bower update** command.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use the following keywords

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "latest",
  "socket.io-client": "latest",
  "underscore": "latest",
  "angular-bootstrap": "latest"
}
```

This shall work when you run **bower update** command.

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna